# What is this mystery component

Tags: wiring, telephone

My father and I have been re-wiring our home's telephone lines, and in doing so, we found these components attached to loose wires.

[image: Mystery Components]

They are both labelled "3M". One says "C22" and the other says "B27".

I think they might be end caps for the wires, but we've never seen anything similar. Does anyone know what they are?

Comment: look carefully at the inside, there should be place for two wires and then contacts inside there that cut into the wires when the red button is pushed down

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Those look like triples to me.

Comment: These things and *lever-nuts* serve same purposes.

Comment: Ridiculous migration are you kidding?

Comment: Wire "nuts" or splicers.

Comment: Not wire nuts at all. IDC butt-connectors (stay out of the gutter, please), or specifically, being 3M, Scotchloks  http://solutions.3m.com/3MContentRetrievalAPI/BlobServlet?lmd=1413989307000&locale=pt_PT&assetType=MMM_Image&assetId=1361822756031&blobAttribute=ImageFile

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are used to splice (unstripped) wires together. They contain a small piece of metal that joins the wires when the colored part is compressed, as well as some containing a gel that insulates the wires from the elements making them suitable for outdoors use.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense, but why would there only be one wire in each of them?

Comment: So that you don't have a wire exposed at the end.

Comment: I don't follow. You said they're for splicing wires together, but there's only one wire. Were they just used for an unintended purpose?

Comment: They're usually used for splicing wires together. They *can* be used to cap off a single wire. They aren't exactly expensive if you know where to get them.

Comment: The wire sticking out shows it's been used previously and discarded. Some one had been working there in the past and made some splices.